# CodeNameOne LocationManager w/o GPS

Tags: codenameone

on Android device there are at least two options for geolocation:

1. GPS Satellites
2. WiFi & Mobile network location

if #1is checked then `LocationManager.getCurrentLocationSync` gets a proper location but what if only #2 is checked? On my device I simply get `LocationManager.OUT_OF_SERVICE` and thats it...

If I use `LocationManager.getCurrentLocation when #1==false && #2==true` I get null...

How can I read devices location based on WiFi & Mobile network location if GPS is turned off? ( or we are not outdoors for example )

Answer (score 0):

As discussed here (3rd paragraph): http://www.codenameone.com/blog/easy-demos-flip-more.html

You can just define the build hint: `android.includeGPlayServices=true`

Which will implicitly switch the location API to use the Google Play Services hybrid location. This will use the GPS when available, but also many other sensor elements to produce a more accurate and battery efficient location.

Comment: thank you! does it work the simmilar way on iOS? ( sorry to stupid question I'm not an iOS eveloper )

Comment: also this hint does not work for android 2.2? natively I can make use of WiFi & Mobile network location on Android 2.2, why this is not working with CN1?

Comment: That is a pretty complex set of API's on Android for a version that is no longer used by many. You can access those API's with native interfaces if you really want them but I would suggest moving forward rather than backwards